# ListView onScrollListener doesn't work

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a problem. My onScrollListener doesnt work, while onItemClickListener that goes right after onScrollListener is working prefectly.
Here is my code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tracks, container, false);

        list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

        list.setOnScrollListener(new ListView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                 int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                Log.d("SCROLL", "SCROLL");
            }
        });

list.setOnItemClickListener( new ListView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            mediaPlayerStart(position);
        }
    });

}
```

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPD:**
I've added toast. Still nothing. Maybe the reason can be that Tracks is a Fragment?

Comment: Post your "working" onItemClickListener to check differences

Comment: Seems like all is fine, may be you simply don't see the logs, try to show toast.

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();

Comment: @ДимаРодионов your code is fine , may be problem with your logcat

Comment: Share your XML code

Comment: @Oleg Vladimirov, it's not a problem of a logcat. Toast is not showed too.

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public ListView list;

```
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();

//DEFINING A STRING ADAPTER WHICH WILL HANDLE THE DATA OF THE LISTVIEW
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {

listItems.add(" "+String.valueOf(i));
}
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnScrollListener(new ListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            Log.d("SCROLL", String.valueOf(scrollState));
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                             int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        //    Log.d("SCROLL", "SCROLL");
        }
    });

    list.setOnItemClickListener( new ListView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
          //  mediaPlayerStart(position);
            Log.d("Click", String.valueOf(position));
        }
    });

}
```

}
try this code ....it will help you..

Comment: No. It didn't help me. Maybe because my adapter is a seperate class, or because the only difference from my code is adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

For the toast, make sure that you call `toast.show()` else it won't show up.

Also make sure that the Activity which contains this fragment properly adds it:

eg-

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new yourFragment()).commit();
```

Comment: toast.show() is called. And yes, i've added fragment